# bootstrap collapsible is toggling out but not in

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On [my project here](http://transgourmet-dev-static.transgourmet.plusline.net/?q=schweizer-weiderind) I have trouble with Bootstrap Collapsible.Please have a look at the screenshot.

[image: download section].

The collapsibles are toggling out on click on the chevron icon as they should but they don't toogle in on the next click like in this Fiddle:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I implemented this into my site pretty much the same way, like in the code snippet. What I've done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please link to a page where you have collapsible panels as I can't see any?

Comment: The Link is correct, there are just below the map. :)

Comment: Ah yes, I was viewing the page on a smaller window and it was being hidden.

Comment: Yes I should have notice, that this feature is only avaiable to desktop sizes...sorry for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem,
i have checked your page source.

you have included

```
<script src="http://transgourmet-dev-static.transgourmet.plusline.net/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/2.1/jquery.min.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
```

then after few scripts you have included again jquery

```
<script src="http://transgourmet-dev-static.transgourmet.plusline.net/sites/all/themes/transgourmet/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js?o1s650"></script>
```

i have just removed the first and and found your problem is resolved , but for some reason your other CSS part not shown well. 
so conclusion is you have jquery conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, i killed the 1.11.3 but the problem persists :(

Comment: yeah i already told you, some of your menus dose not looks well as per your css. there might some other conflict. i am just checking

Comment: remove first 2 script. . 

jquery.min.js?v=2.1.4

and jquery.once.js?v=1.2


keep jquery-1.11.3.min.js?o1s650

Comment: Actually what i did. i copied your entire page source and checked one by one, run it on a local and  then removed the first 2 script i have mentioned above and found it is working.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. Now that you know my site, May I ask you to have a look t a related problem? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711920/2-scroll-bars-on-one-page-handicap-each-other